# Restful service inside project repository

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am making a restful api for that should access a photo repository.
I wanted to use MySQL but I faced some problems with columns.

My question is, what is the best data structure I can use for storing photos inside project. A hashmap? Or is there any light weighted database that can be embeded ?

Comment: *I faced some problems with columns*. Which problems? MySQL is perfectly able to store photos. If you decide to change your database every time you face a problem, you'll probably change very often :)

Comment: [BLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) or a path/url to the image data

Comment: Exactly another problem is without outputstream can I show the picture , what is the best way to convert BLOB to image